# Pig - Get Max Count

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Sample Data

```
DATE      WindDirection

1/1/2000  SW
1/2/2000  SW
1/3/2000  SW
1/4/2000  NW
1/5/2000  NW
```

Question below

Every day is unqiue, and wind direction is not unique, SO now we are trying    to get the COUNT of the most COMMON wind direction

My query was

```
weather_data = FOREACH Weather GENERATE $16 AS Date, $9 AS w_direction;
e = FOREACH weather_data 
            {
                unique_winds = DISTINCT weather_data.w_direction;
                GENERATE unique_winds, COUNT(unique_winds);
            }
dump e;
```

The logic is to find the DISTINCT WindDirections (there are like 7), then group by `WindDirection` and apply count.

Right now I think get the total number or count of directions of winds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to GROUP BY wind direction and get the counts.Order the counts by desc order and get the top most row.

```
wd = FOREACH Weather GENERATE $9 AS w_direction;
gwd = GROUP wd BY w_direction;
cwd = FOREACH gwd GENERATE group as wd,COUNT(wd.$0);
owd = ORDER cwd BY $1 DESC;
mwd  = LIMIT owd 1;
DUMP mwd;
```